# Workflow page not fully appearing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow

I moved a site from one server to another.

If I go to any document library such as Pages and try to edit or add a new workflow for e.g. **Approval - SharePoint 2010** or **Publishing workflow** then it only shows first screen where I can enter workflow name and choose other options, and when I click next, it shows a blank page as shown in screenshot.

What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed the problem and it looks like this is a bug in SharePoint.

My alternate access URL has an underscore in it and removing it solved the problem.

No idea why SharePoint doesn't like underscore in URLs.